# Testing how many time a for loop has run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

Hi I have a method witch has two for loops.The method looks like this:

```
 public ElearningSessionsDTO FilterElearningSession(IEnumerable<GetELearningSessionsForStudent_Result> eLearningSession)
    {
        var eLearningSessionDTO = new ElearningSessionsDTO();
        var clossedLessons = new List<LessonsInElearningDTO>();
        var plannedLessons = new List<LessonsInElearningDTO>();

        var groupLessons = eLearningSession.GroupBy(key => new { key.LessonNumber, key.LessonTitle, key.TargetDate },
                                                    data => new { data.Status, data.EventTitle });

        foreach (var groupLesson in groupLessons)
        {
            bool isPlanned = false;

            var lessonInElearningDTO = new LessonsInElearningDTO
            {
                LessonNumber = groupLesson.Key.LessonNumber,
                LessonTitle = groupLesson.Key.LessonTitle,
                TargetDate = groupLesson.Key.TargetDate
            };
            var assignmentsInLessonDTO = new List<AssignmentsInLessonDTO>();

            foreach (var assignment in groupLesson)
            {
                var assignmentInLessonDTO = new AssignmentsInLessonDTO
                {
                    EventTitle = assignment.EventTitle,
                    Status = assignment.Status
                };

                if (assignment.Status != (int)ElearningEventSubscriptionStatuses.Closed)
                {
                    isPlanned = true;
                }
                assignmentsInLessonDTO.Add(assignmentInLessonDTO);
            }

            lessonInElearningDTO.LessonsAssignments = assignmentsInLessonDTO;

            if (isPlanned)
            {
                plannedLessons.Add(lessonInElearningDTO);
            }
            else
            {
                clossedLessons.Add(lessonInElearningDTO);
            }
        }

        eLearningSessionDTO.ClossedLessons = clossedLessons;
        eLearningSessionDTO.PlannedLessons = plannedLessons;

        return eLearningSessionDTO;
    }
```

I want two create two unit tests for it.One for verifying how many times the first foreach loop was called.And the second for verifying how many times the second foreach loop was called.

I am using moq as my mocking framework and normally in this kind of scenarios I would have some aditional method called from an external class and using that I would be able to determine how many times in a loop that method was called.But in my current scenario I can not find a way to test this.

Can anyone give some Ideea on how I should proceed?

Comment: There are no `for` loops in your code, just `foreach` loops. Also seems a bizarre mode of testing with such an embedded piece of logic. I mean, are you wanting to verify that `foreach` actually works, or that your code doesn't make it fail, or what?

Comment: If you cannot access it with moq, then it's a private implementation detail of your method. It's very likely to be a bad idea to pin these private numbers down through unit testing.

Comment: It is an internal implementation and not something you should be counting / checking. What if you refactor your code and find you don't need to do two for loops? Your tests would fail even though the outcome of the method would still be correct.

Comment: You should populate your `IEnumerable<GetELearningSessionsForStudent_Result>` input parameter and assert to see if your `ElearningSessionsDTO` is populated as expected instead.  As others have already stated, your internal implementation might change and it is therefore unwise to couple your test to your implementation details.